# The wording on reputation changes about downvoting is confusing

Tags: discussion

On the reputation tab on the user's activity page, the "-2" when your posts are downvoted by other people is described as *downvote*, whereas the "-1" when you downvote other people's posts is described as *downvoted*.

[image]

I'm not a native English speaker, but this wording doesn't make sense to me. In fact, it sounds like backwards — "downvoted" sounds like passively getting your posts downvoted, whereas "downvote" indicates actively downvoting on other people's posts.

Comment: "downvoted" is a unambiguously a verb.  Verbs are action words.  Make the shortest sentence out of it that starts with "you".

Comment: @HansPassant Then shouldn't "upvote" and "accept" be changed to "was upvoted" and "was accepted"?

Comment: I agree it's mildly confusing. Once you've read it more than twice it should become second nature. I don't even look at the word there, just the numbers, if I ever look at it at all...

Comment: I can't keep up with that mental leap.  I merely suggested a way to not be confused.  There isn't much else but "you downvoted" and "you got a downvote".

Comment: I think the distinction is who did the action. You _downvoted_ an answer, or someone else gave your post a _downvote_ (or an accept, an upvote, etc).

Comment: It's a little weird (if this is the case) that there's a difference between having one as a verb and the others as nouns, but whatever.

Comment: While I agree it is a bit unintuitive, I suspect changing it now would cause far more confusion than just leaving it the way it is.

Comment: Do you have a request?

Comment: You lost 2 points because you received a downvote. You lost 1 point because you downvoted an answer. Makes sense to me.

Comment: FWIW I agree that it should be "accepted" instead of "accept" for consistency.

Comment: The two sound interchangeable. Why did I lose one point? Downvote. Or downvoted. Why did I lose two points? Downvote. Or downvoted. Whether I'm on the giving or receiving end, the same two things occur. The action - someone downvoted, and the result - a downvote.

Comment: Because English ...

Comment: One thing not seen here is "removed", referring to when a previously downvoted or upvoted post is deleted, which adds yet another wrinkle :).

Comment: @HansPassant It's NOT unambiguously a verb. It's also an adjective. "You were downvoted".

Comment: @MaxLanghof it should only say "accepted" if you were the one that accepted an answer, not if your answer was accepted. Right now it seems that _if someone else did the action_, it uses the form without -ed (upvote, downvote, accept), but if _you did the action_, it treats it more like a verb (upvoted, downvoted, accepted).

Comment: Easy solution: Don't get downvoted. Then it will be easy to identify which is which. :D

Comment: @Broman Just because I'm an obnoxioux nitpicker about things that don't matter, "You were downvoted" isn't using "downvoted" as an adjective, it's using it as a past participle of the verb tense called a [verbal](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm); an example of it being an adjective would be "The downvoted user came to Meta to complain."

Comment: @DavyM I stand corrected

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I understand the problem. The words are a bit confusing. They're differentiated by a single character, and it's not immediately obvious which one means which. You can get used to it, but it is weird.

The problem is that there's not really a better solution. All of the clearer ways to phrase them are also *longer*. The column where these appear is narrow and it should be. "downvoted" is already the longest thing that appears in that column, and any more clear word or phrase will be longer still.

That being said, there is a consistency issue that can be worked out. There should be a consistent difference between things you do to a post (upvote/downvote/accept) and things done to your posts (upvoted/downvoted/accepted). That won't run into any layout issues. Right now, things are rather inconsistent; "accept" is used for both cases, while we have the "downvote/downvoted" distinction.

Comment: Maybe highlight the reputation you actively gained/lost (probably only downvotes) or the other way around, highlight the passive reputation you gained/lost

Answer (score 12):

## Unambiguous:

- `[You]` cast `[a]` downvote.
- `[You]` received `[a]` downvote.

Just putting a qualifier of `cast` or `received` would make it unambiguous.

- downvote cast
- downvote received

Either way I took [this to English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501022/what-would-be-the-best-terminology-for-the-following-discussion). Let's see what they have to say about it before making any changes.

The argument about the column being narrow is just lazy justification for not doing anything. For the record, it is **2019** and everyone has at least 1080P monitor for a decade, of which StackOverflow wastes 2/3 of the horizontal screen real-estate for absolutely no reason.

**There is no defendable practical reason that the layout can not be made slightly wider and the user experience made more semantically unambiguous.**

Comment: English.SE would not necessarily be useful, since there are layout issues that take priority.

Comment: This doesn't work with the rest of the format for that section.

Comment: I think the body of that question should be able to stand on its own, without the title (e.g., it does not form an actual question; it only has statements). The context is in the link, but it shouldn't be necessary to open a link; the question ought to be self-contained. The title could also be more specific and descriptive. And it is probably a good idea to not use the word "discussion" on a non-meta Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Maybe more for [ux.se] instead.

Comment: @NicolBolas:layout take priority over human culture: exactly this what we need. In general the developers do not need to create applications what serve users purposes, instead users must serve and adopt their  work an everyday life to the applications. Developer rulez!

Answer (score 8):

This is a rather minor issue in my opinion, and not really a problem that needs to be solved.

Most of the reasoning here is consistency.

An upvote is +10, a downvote is -2.

The word downvoted is certainly a little awkward though, as it seems to imply you were downvoted, not that you downvoted something.

If you look at accept, for example, if you get an answer accepted, it is +15 reputation, if you accept an answer (other than your own) it is +2 reputation. However, in the list you see

accept is +15, accept is +2.

Perhaps it just makes sense to change downvote to either -2 received or -1 cast. To those who would argue "but grouping", that is not possible. You cannot receive a downvote on an answer you downvote; you cannot cast a downvote on an answer you received a downvote on.

downvote is -2, downvote is -1.

Comment: "_as it seems to imply you were downvoted_" I didn't get this implication from reading it. Mostly because if I'm looking at _my profile_, I see "downvoted", I immediately think "I did this action" (it's a verb), but if I see "downvote" my thought is "someone downvoted me" (because I gained a downvote, I didn't do an action)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - As you highlight, there are awkward implications of having both words present. While I may interpret it one way, you (and others) will interpret it another. This is the problem with having awkward wording. Luckily, it doesn't really cause any harm since it is rather evident with even the slightest amount of investigation what the reference meant, is not prominently displayed, and also has essentially no negative side effects.

Answer (score 5):

IMO, it's been a long-time problem.

I would vote for that +5's and +10's should be renamed into "upvoted", and -2's being "downvoted" (past participle), while -1's should be "downvote" (not using past simple to avoid confusion).

Because you're the object of the action (upv / downv / accept), it makes more sense to me, as one with English as a foreign language, to use the past participle to indicate this. Downvoting others' answers are better described with an indicative form of the verb, but with English where for regular verbs past indicative and past participle don't make a difference, sticking to the present indicative might be a better idea.

(Off-topic) With French this would not be a problem: -2's are described with *voté* while -1's would be described with *votais* (past indicative, meaning "I voted" / "you voted").